# Javascript - Does't work foreach loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with the foreach loop. Written code using the foreach loop does not work but if I use the for loops everything works as it should. I look for solution in internet few hours and nothing. I put two examples. First example is use foreach loop and second example is use for loop. Sorry but my english is not the best.

Example - foreach loop (broken):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  test();
};


function test() {
  let testDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));
  let currentTest = testDiv[0];
  currentTest.className += " test2";
   testDiv.forEach((current) => {
    current.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      currentTest.className = currentTest.className.replace("test2", "");
      currentTest = this;
      currentTest.className += " test2";
    });
  }); 
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/script.js" async></script>  
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div>
    <div class="test">1</div>
    <div class="test">2</div>
    <div class="test">3</div>
    <div class="test">4</div>
    <div class="test">5</div>
  </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Example - for loop (works fine):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  test();
};


function test() {
  let testDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));
  let currentTest = testDiv[0];
  currentTest.className += " test2";
  for (var i = 0; i < testDiv.length; i++) {
   testDiv[i].onmouseover = function() {
    currentTest.className = currentTest.className.replace("test2", "");
    currentTest = this;
    currentTest.className += " test2";
   };
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/script.js" async></script>  
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div>
    <div class="test">1</div>
    <div class="test">2</div>
    <div class="test">3</div>
    <div class="test">4</div>
    <div class="test">5</div>
  </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with `for` vs. `forEach`, it's about `function` vs. `=>` functions.

```
//                                    vvvvv
current.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  currentTest.className = currentTest.className.replace("test2", "");
  currentTest = this;
//              ^^^^
```

That `this` does not have the value you expect because you used an arrow function, which binds `this` from the surrounding context (instead of getting it passed it from the `mousemove` event).

To fix it, do this instead:

```
current.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
  currentTest.className = currentTest.className.replace("test2", "");
  currentTest = this;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `this` which is not your `current` element.

You need to set `currentTest` to `current`, like this:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  test();
};


function test() {
  let testDiv = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));
  let currentTest = testDiv[0];
  currentTest.className += " test2";
   testDiv.forEach((current) => {
    current.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      currentTest.className = currentTest.className.replace("test2", "");
      currentTest = current;
      currentTest.className += " test2";
    });
  }); 
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/script.js" async></script>  
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div>
    <div class="test">1</div>
    <div class="test">2</div>
    <div class="test">3</div>
    <div class="test">4</div>
    <div class="test">5</div>
  </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would add to the answer the main difference between arrow function's lexical context for `this` and "normal" functions with dynamic context for `this`